# How to get all people and their name and wikipedia link from DBPedia SparQL?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am getting these results:

```
[
  ...
  {
    resource: {
      type: 'uri',
      value: 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Benjamin_Swan_(Vermont)'
    },
    name: {
      type: 'literal',
      'xml:lang': 'en',
      value: 'Balogun Yakub Abiodun'
    }
  },
  {
    resource: {
      type: 'uri',
      value: 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Benjamin_Swan_(Vermont_politician)'
    },
    name: {
      type: 'literal',
      'xml:lang': 'en',
      value: 'Balogun Yakub Abiodun'
    }
  },
  {
    resource: {
      type: 'uri',
      value: 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Benjamin_Swearer'
    },
    name: {
      type: 'literal',
      'xml:lang': 'en',
      value: 'Balogun Yakub Abiodun'
    }
  },
  {
    resource: {
      type: 'uri',
      value: 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Benjamin_Sweet'
    },
    name: {
      type: 'literal',
      'xml:lang': 'en',
      value: 'Balogun Yakub Abiodun'
    }
  }
  ...
]
```

For this query:

```
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT ?resource ?name
WHERE {
  ?resource  rdf:type  dbo:Person .
  ?person a dbo:Person .
  ?person dbp:name ?name .
  FILTER (LANG(?name) = 'en') .
}
offset 0
limit 50
```

The `resource` is linking to an English-named resource, yet the name returned is not English, even though marked as English. How do I just get the people names and their wikipedia links? It also appears I am requesting two separate things perhaps... How would you get their photo as well?

This is what I've ended up with but it seems to be returning things like `List of Scottish X`, and other non-people links.

```
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT ?resource ?name ?depiction
WHERE {
  ?resource  rdf:type  dbo:Person .
  ?resource dbp:name ?name .
  ?resource foaf:depiction ?depiction .
  FILTER (LANG(?name) = 'en') .
}
order by ?name
offset 0
limit 50
```

Comment: why are you doing ` ?resource  rdf:type  dbo:Person .
  ?person a dbo:Person .` in your first query? The variables should be the same.

Comment: the names are just extracted form the English Wikipedia infoboxes - all data is just extracted mostly from the Wikipedia infoboxes. Not all people have an image. I'd do: `PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT ?person ?name ?wikipage ?depiction
WHERE {
  ?person a dbo:Person .
  ?person dbp:name ?name .
  FILTER (LANG(?name) = 'en') .
 ?person foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?wikipage .
OPTIONAL {?person foaf:depiction ?depiction }
}
offset 0
limit 50`